# Making a typeahead with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I currently use AngularJS and Bootstrap.
I want to make a typeahead which show all options when he is selected (when I click on it) not only when I wrote somthing on it. like the example on [this site](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) which use JQuery (I can't use JQuery).

here is my controller

```
countrycatControllers.controller('CountryListCtrl',['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.listCountry = [
        {"name": "Switzerland"},
        {"name": "France"},
        {"name": "Spain"},
        {"name": "Brazil"},
        {"name": "Argentina"},
        {"name": "USA"},
        {"name": "Canada"},
        {"name": "China"},
        {"name": "Germany"},
        {"name": "Italy"}
        ];
    }
])
```

and here is my HTML input :

```
<pre>Model: {{country | json}}</pre>
<input data-ng-model="country" typeahead="item.name for item in listCountry | filter:$viewValue"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an 100% angular directive for the Select2 plugin.

Check out **https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on your own by using filter:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="CountryListCtrl">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter country here" ng-model="search.name" size="80" ng-focus="modeExpanded=true" ng-blur="modeExpanded=false" />
            <div ng-show="modeExpanded">
                <div ng-repeat="item in listCountry | filter:search">{{item.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. The idea is that the search model mimics the structure of the listCountry entries. ng-focus and ng-blur are used to get show the list only when you actually click on the input element.

Comment: thanks for your idea but I'm trying to use a real typeahead like in my example